# Can you pass in an Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate into a linq Where statement?

Tags: c#

So I have a method similar to this:

```
public List<T> SomeFunction(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    return someList.Where(predicate).ToList();
}
```

This code is not compileable because I cannot pass in the predicate to the linq Where statement. Is there a way to change the predicate in order to use it with linq?

Comment: I think you need to change the method signature to `public List<T> SomeFunction<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)`

Comment: you can pass `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate` into linq `where` for `IQueryable`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `Enumerable.Where` method, then you need to compile your expression

```
public List<T> SomeFunction(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
    return someList.Where(predicate.Compile()).ToList();
}
```

Also think about whether you really need to use expression here. You can simply pass `Func<T, bool>`

Comment: It would be better to notice, that `predicate.Compile()` will be performance hit in case of frequent calls. I think, OP doesn't understand the difference between `Expression<SomeDelegate>` and `SomDelegate`.

Comment: @Dennis as far as I know Expression is designed mainly to provide some way to transfer expressions from client to the server, evaluate expressions there and get back the result. In this case, `Compile()` just returns a normal delegate, so how can it be better than a normal `Func<...>`? I know the word `Compile` may confuse many people, we know that every **compiled thing** would be faster, however in this case `Compile()` is just a method turning the expression to an executable form (a delegate).

Comment: @KingKing: expressions are the way to represent code as a tree. That is they were designed for. Transferring expressions from client to server in n-tier solutions is just an application example (and not the main one). The other part of your comment should be addressed to the OP, because I can't understand, what you're trying to explain to me? I know, what `Expression.Compile` does, and I'm trying to warn OP, that it will be performance hit.

Comment: Thank you! that worked. And this code is just used in test and will be used sparsely, so the performance isn't a factor.

Comment: @Dennis what I want to mean here is `Expression.Compile()` returns a delegate, so it will not be a performance hit compared to using `Func<...>`. `represent code as a tree` -> this is needed because the server side can understand and run the code correctly.

Comment: @Dennis OK, I may misunderstand you something, because the last sentence of `lazy...` is `You can simply pass Func<T, bool>`, I thought you might suggest to better use Expression here.

Comment: @KingKing: you're missing something. The call of the *compiled delegate* will be as fast, as the `Func<T, bool>` call. But the *compilation* of the delegate, which will take place for every `predicate.Compile` call, will significantly degrade performance. Note, that code in the answer doesn't cache compiled instance.

Comment: @Dennis yes, better declare some variable storing the compiled instance once.

Comment: @KingKing sorry if my last sentence is confusing :) I just wanted to say - if OP uses Enumerable extensions, then he probably don't need to use expressions here (there is no need to analyze expression tree), so it's better to change parameter type to `Func` and use simple delegate here

Comment: @lazyberezovsky in fact it did not confuse me :), I can understand it, I might just misunderstand the comment of Dennis.